# Recognize value type depends on key

Tags: typescript

I have different paths of a model like "a", "a.b", "a.b.c". I want to return correct type for **value**

Example

```
type MyFirstResultType = "1"
type MySecondResultType = "2"

type A = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: MyFirstResultType;
    };
  };
  d: {
    e: MySecondResultType;
  };
};

type PathValue<T, P extends string> = P extends `${infer K}.${infer Rest}`
  ? K extends keyof T
    ? PathValue<T[K], Rest>
    : never
  : P extends keyof T
    ? T[P]
    : never;

type Result1 = PathValue<A, "d.e">;
type Result2 = PathValue<A, "a.b.c">;
```

How do I obtain the correct type based on the key that is being passed?

```
type ObjType = {
  key: "d.e" | "a.b.c"; // Should be FieldPath<A>.Just ignore this type;
  value: "??"; // Should be PathValue<A, "d.e"> | PathValue<A, "a.b.c">;
};

const resultObj1: ObjType = {
  key: "d.e",
  value: "????", // Must be MyFirstResultType according key path
};

const resultObj2: ObjType = {
  key: "a.b.c",
  value: "???", // Must be MySecondResultType according key path
};
```

Comment: Where are they being passed? These are simple object declarations which could have anything unless you manually specify the type there. If they are supposed to be arguments to some function, you can easily use generics there  - https://tsplay.dev/w6e7eW

Comment: Could you please take another look? Our goal is to avoid incorporating additional functions and achieve this solely using TypeScript. Overall, I'm uncertain about its feasibility.

Comment: something like this maybe? https://tsplay.dev/WPOyJm or maybe https://tsplay.dev/Nlz6GW

Comment: @brc-dd It seems that you've explicitly defined the type as Result<"a.b.c"> | Result<"d.e">. Its not an extendable solution. However, in our scenario, we have numerous models with a variety of fields, and our aim is for a solution that can function as a generic approach.

Comment: Have you checked the second link in that comment? It's using mapped types. That should be pretty much extensible. Or if you want to use generics instead of FieldPath there, you can do https://tsplay.dev/mAL3ZN

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your understanding regarding the delayed response. I'd like to discuss an alternative approach. Instead of a generic solution, you might consider avoiding predefining the path as in type ```FieldPath = "a.b.c" | "d.e"```. This could be challenging whenever there's a need to add new paths. What are your thoughts on exploring a more adaptable solution?

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/m3KZkm ?

Comment: or https://tsplay.dev/wXg6JW

Comment: or if you're using type-fest - https://tsplay.dev/wOX6pN

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, I use react-hook-form. The example at tsplay.dev/m3KZkm seems well-suited for my needs. I believe I can adapt it to work with classes, as T may be a class. It appears to be a suitable solution for the question at hand. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.