# TypeScript keyof typeof nested properties

Tags: typescript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
const obj = {
  a: "a",
  b: {
    c: 1,
  },
};
```

I want to build a type that allows only the keys to be used in an array:

```
type Arr = (keyof typeof obj)[]
```

This is fine.

But now, I also want to allow nested keys into the array. I mean, the array can also look like this:

```
const arr: Arr = ["a", "b.c"]
```

Any ideas on how to do that using TypeScript?

I don't want to allow string:

```
type Arr = (keyof typeof obj | string)[]
```

But not sure if possible to enforce that typesafety in the array.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=32&pln=8&pc=38#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGBDAXDAES5EA02M8hWOOwhAjBTgL4WsDcmmUAngAcApjACCAJ3GoYACgDWQviABmMfsJVwkMAD4xo4gJZgA5gEoA2gF0eoSLFyTCEqWgslyxeADpgRG0A).

Comment: If you're using type-fest, you can use `Paths` and do `type Arr = Paths<typeof obj>[]` If you want to manually write up that, you can either refer their implementation or my comments on this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/q/77820353/11613622

Comment: Use `Leaves` or `Paths` from the answer to [the above linked q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLO8vN), depending on what your use case is.